# JMP rel16 (instead of JMP rel32)

Tags: assembly, x86, exploit, opcode

I need to make a jump opcode for an exploit demonstration.

I need to jump to about 200 bytes after the jump instruction. This is too much for a `jmp short`.

If I generate an opcode with a regular jump, `jmp $200` I get this:

```
e9 fb 01 00 00
```

The problem here is that opcode contains 00 which is interpreted as an end of string when passing the string to the program (as such I can't pass the full shellcode with this in it).

I thought my approach was screwed but then [I checked the manual](http://microsym.com/editor/assets/386intel.pdf) and on the second line there is apparently a "near jump" that takes 2 bytes (there's also the other one that takes 4 bytes, the one I showed above). Both these jumps start with the same byte, `e9`.

How can I pass `e9 fb 01` as the near jump that takes only two bytes arguments? How do I prevent the OS from looking for four bytes after the `e9`, ie: `e9 fb 01 90 90`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the program as string? Can you use length prefixed string?

Comment: It's definately not the OS which is looking for four bytes, it's the processor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot.

The 0xE9 opcode uses a 32-bit offset when the processor is running in 32-bit mode, and a 16-bit offset only when the processor is in 16-bit mode.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. I take it there is no way of doing this relative jump without null bytes then.

Comment: Technically, that's not true. You can use an operand size override. The problem with that is that the destination EIP will be masked to 16 bits. @Juicy: as a workaround, you might use 2 jumps to bridge the gap.

Comment: @Jester Thanks I'll see if I can find a way to do this with two short jumps somehow

Comment: @Jester Yeah I found out about the `66` operand in another post but like you said, it masks to a 16 bit destination `eip` so it's not helping.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the current EIP address within the shellcode and the memory area is writeable you could do something like this:

```
; say in ECX you have shellcode start address
; (calculated with delta offset etc.)
_start:

...

; ECX = offset _start

; decrypt zero bytes in jmp instruction relative address

; 80 69 xx  AB
sub byte ptr[ecx+(_fix1-_start)], 0ABh

; 80 69 xx+1 BA
sub byte ptr[ecx+(_fix2-_start) + 1], 0BAh

; jmp instruction with those 00s encrypted
_jmp  db 0E9h, 0FBh, 01h ; first 3 bytes of jmp near instruction
_fix1 db 0 + 0ABh        ; encrypted displacement (last 2 bytes)
_fix2 db 0 + 0BAh
```

So the relative address encoded in `jmp near` instruction doesn't contain 00s, but at runtime those bytes are restored.

Keep in mind that the decryption instruction might contain 00s also if the difference from the calculation `(_fix1-_start)` contains zeros, more probably if the generated instruction is the long form of sub [r32 + imm32], imm8), so check it manually too.

Comment: If you have access to EIP you can just do an indirect jump, no need to mess with self-modifying code.

Comment: Well you could always calculate it with delta offset or FPU (latest executed instruction), so it's not a big deal in code to get the current EIP.